# System freezes during boot after failed upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, dns

I was running an upgrade from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10. About 80% of the way through KDE crashed and the system became unresponsive. I restart and now the system hangs during boot and I am unable to drop into the terminal by pressing alt-F4.

If I run recovery mode in order to repair broken packages I get an error: 'Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file of directory (g-io-error-quark, 1). Searching around for this error seems to indicate that I have an invalid mount point defined in /ect/fstab.

If i try to repair the broken packages manually I find that the network is down, so I try to bring the network back up with:

sudo ifup eth0

I get an ip address from the router but then again i get the error:

Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)

followed by

resolvconf: Error: /run/resolvconf/interface either does not exist or is not a directory
bound to 192.168.1.15 -- renewal in 253997 seconds.
resolvconf: Error: /run/resolvconf/interface either does not exist or is not a directory
grep: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory

However when I run

ls -l /etc/resolv.conf

I can see that the file is present and that I have full read write permissions. Can anyone shed any light onto what has gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I still have not managed to solve this problem. Could it be a RAID issue?

Comment: RAID checks out ok with live CD.